# Eclipse Project - need to have a copy locally and a copy on a remote server

Tags: eclipse, synchronization, zend-studio

I develop in PHP using Zend Studio - operating as an Eclipse plugin - has a really nice feature called "Automatic Upload" that can be configured on a per Project basis. This feature allows one to define a remote connection to a server for a Project, and also specify whether file copy to the remote server is "manual" or "on save".

We use the "on save" option extensively, as it allows us to edit a file via Eclipse, save it, and immediately see the file in play on our remote web server.

Specifically the functionality we are after is as follows:

1. Create or edit a local file in Eclipse
2. On Save of the local copy, automatically creates / updates the remote copy
3. On Delete of the local copy, deletes the remote copy

(cut/copy & paste behave in a conceptually equivalent way)

and

Manual batch  "upload to remote" and "download from remote" menu options that allows full upload / download of all files as well as manual cherry picking of files to upload or download.

This feature is really nice and has very broad application so I expected it to be standard Eclipse functionality, however I have installed Eclipse Oxygen, and can't find it. I have subsequently done rather a lot of searching, and although there are some manual options that have appeared, the closest I can find to an automated copy equivalent is the Parallel Development Tools plug-in which provides a "Synchronized Project" option.

Synchronized Projects require git running on both local and remote and a git folder structure inserted into the Project. Additionally, hidden files are injected into every Project sub-folder.

The above renders Synchronized Projects too "heavy" and potentially problematic to manage for us.

So I am fairly desperately looking for an Eclipse Oxygen (or Neon is fine) plug-in that provides the functionality outlined above.

Your input is greatly welcomed. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

While not exactly remote sync, a little lateral thinking has given me exactly what we need. What I did is as follows:

**Remote (linux)**

1. Install Samba
2. Use Samba to present the desired folder as a Windows share

**Local (PC)**

*Windows File explorer*

- mapped the remote windows share to a local mapped drive

*Eclipse*

- downloaded and installed the [***File Sync*** plug-in from Eclipse market place](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-sync)
- right-clicked on my Project and selected Properties => File synchronisation, and configured the desired folders (setting the "remote" as the mapped drive)
- and one final item (because we are mapping from a Windows local to a Linux remote) : Window => Preferences => General => Workspace Set "New text file line delimiter" to "Other => Unix"

And hey presto, everything is working 100%.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by [a project builder Ant buildfile](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-93_project_builder.htm). Alternative, there are others build system that are implements the Eclipse project builder (to be executed on save), but which must be installed separately. You can also implement your own [incremental project builder](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/resAdv_builders.htm) in Java.

Comment: thanks so much for the feedback. Unusually, I have had a bit of a brainwave and resolved the problem in a slightly different - and astoundingly simple - manner, giving us exactly what we need ("answer" is below)

Comment: @Pancho Okay, great. I upvoted the answer by yourself.